# What is discard layers in Photoshop saving TIFF?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, tiff

When I am saving TIFF in Photoshop, I can "Discard Layers":

[image]

In this case, image becomes several times smaller, for example 25M image can become 12M image and even smaller.

What is it and what I am loosing?

Answer (score 1):

Some apps cannot open multi-layer TIFFs, so this option will flatten the image to a single layer before saving - which is why it offers to save as a copy, rather than overwrite your multi-layer original.

The space saving you are seeing is the result of it being reduced to a single layer.

Comment: Why does reducing to single layer make size smaller? Images came from scanner, were put into several pages of one TIFF, then splitted by ImageMagick.

Comment: Could it be that Photoshop interprets multi-page TIFFs as layered images, and by flattening layers only keeps the 1st page?